# Create authorization header in oath1 with signature Method HMAC-SHA256, consumer key and consumer Secret only

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-1.0a, spring-boot-starter-security

I want to create below Authorization header with signature Method HMAC-SHA256, consumer key and consumer Secret only for oAuth1 security. I tried multiple ways but wasn't able to get the correct value.

Please help me. I am trying to create authorization header in java.

example:

```
addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\",oauth_timestamp=\"1635314286\",oauth_nonce=\"JcxiA8z1V6e\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"9Xt21rhLVqFPoc%2FBPxnpfJ9%2BQTKEr1NEkPQMHOY2L7s%3D\"")
```